# Color scheme hard to read

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, bug

The color scheme on the priviledges page is so dark, it's barely readable. So is the red warning messages I get while posting. Tried multiple browsers, multiple PC's, pretty much the same everywhere.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed on live, both the main site and Meta

Comment: Much better now.