# Red color of "you can't create new tags" warning text hardly readable against background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If, as a user without sufficient reputation, you try to create a new tag, you'll get a warning message next to the tag input line. Look for

```
<div id="ask-error-container" class="form-error">
```

It's coloured a deep red, which is barely readable against the dark grey background.

There was an [older entry](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/color-scheme-hard-to-read) here that mentions something similar, but I think that author was referring to other parts of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.